# App isn't installed error when using In-App Promo SDK on Android 13

Tags: android

I followed this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/in-app-promo-sdk#0) to implement **in-app promo SDK**, everything works fine but when you update the **targetSdkVersion** to **33** (Android 13), if you try any shortcut you'll get a Toast message displaying **"App isn't installed"** and it doesn't open the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add an **VIEW action** to your Activity in the **AndroidManifest.xml** and it will open the app without any errors.

```
<intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```